# What's a normal response delay for a paragliding vario?

Tags: flight-instruments, paraglider

I'm a paragliding pilot with P4 licence and I've purchased a 2nd-hand FLYMASTER B1NAV flight instrument for XC flights – mainly for logging the flights *(route, distance, max. speed etc)*. It is an Altimeter-Variometer-GPS combo. As you know, these devices warn the pilot with beeps during climbing and sinking.

I'm using the device for a couple of months but I *recently* noticed an interesting thing: When I enter the thermal I first feel the climb with my harness and risers. But the device starts to beep with a delay of 1-2 seconds.

Is this normal?

I know it's an old and discontinued product. I've looked into its manual, but couldn't find any info about the delay. I don't want to rate this device as "broken", but I cannot be sure.

Comment: PS you'll probably get better answers by posting to a dedicated paragliding forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably normal.  I notice a similar delay when flying with my Brauniger IQ Comp vario (lately mainly in sailplanes.)  Minimizing the delay is why the latest varios incorporate accelerometers as well as barometric pressure sensors.  Sounds like you've already checked the manual to see if there is some way you can decrease the interval of averaging, upon which the primary visual display and audio tone are based.  That adjustment is definitely possible with some variometers produced for hang gliding / paragliding use, but not with all.

Another way to get a quicker response time is to buy a vario that is even older.  For example, check out the "Litek Hummingbird".

Answer (score 2):

That's normal for older varios. **However it's not normal for current products**.

An early form of vario is a flask vario:

[image]

As the instrument rises, the air in the flask will try and rush out of the openings since it will be at a higher pressure than the surroundings. As it rushes past the pith balls, one is forced upwards in the draft. The same thing happens in descent but the other ball is forced upwards.

There is obviously a lag due to friction and inertia.

Modern electronic varios use other sorts of sensor but they are still barometric sensors like this (i.e. they rely on air pressure to give us an indication of altitude and rate of climb).

> In these flight instruments, electronic sensors measure the
> rate-of-change of air pressure, from which climb rate can be
> calculated.
>
> Early varios used a simple needle display with a corresponding audio
> signal. As things went digital designers were able to do more, adding
> averagers and energy compensation. But everything still relied on a
> pressure sensor. ([source](https://xcmag.com/paraglider-reviews/xc-tracer-and-xc-tracer-mini-review/))

These typically have low lag. For example, the BlueFlyVario vario samples a a rate of 50Hz so the minimum lag is 20 ms. With older models perhaps 1 second of lag isn't unheard of.

Nowadays, the latest varios combine many sensors (predominantly an accelerometer and a barometer) but also GPS and gyroscopes to give near zero lag.

So while it's true that some older varios can have lag, **it shouldn't be expected with modern instruments and it's definitely not what you should have to put up with**.

[This](https://vimeo.com/120690172) is a seven year old video showing zero-lag in a tiny vario.

Comment: Dunno whose doing all the dv'ing but keep in mind the question was about the normal behavior *for an older instrument of a specific type*, not about whether that represents the optimum possible design, or even the optimum attainable design at the time the instrument was produced.

Comment: The question was "What's a normal response delay for a paragliding vario?" A subquestion was related to that specific make and model. It would seem useful to the asker to have additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is perfectly normal. It's physically unavoidable to feel the lifting force, that sets a rise into motion, before that rise can be measured. The only faster way I could think of were to measure rope tension instead of altitude.

As for the duration of the delay: The manufacturer knows that there is some measurement noise (fluctuation), and needs to smooth it out. If they determined that the measurement might fluctuate within a 10 cm range in any given second, they will not alert you unless you have climbed 11 cm.

Comment: Why is it physically unavoidable? I don't think it is, after all that's precisely how an accelerometer works. Plus there are varios on the open market that do this.